# scrape span tag on google search yield varying result

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate the process of getting the address of our clients from google search. Essentially what I'm trying to do is as below:

1. keywords saved as a list in a csv file ('abc','def')
2. python to read from csv list for the company name
3. run a for loop through the list
4. replace the string in the url
5. extract the address from the loaded html element,
6. save into csv

I have 2 variable in the codes below:

1. c
2. d

and they both represent the company im searching for, what I have in the for loop eventually is a list of all the companies I need to go through to find whether their address is available on google search. If an address is found from the elements then I will grab it. I've check both page they contain the same element but when I execute the code, 'c' will return the address but 'd' will not. What is missing here?

I would like to see the output to be:

| company | address |
| --- | --- |
| Siong auto enterprise, | Some address |
| DK motor sdn bhd, | some other address |

code is attached

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from time import sleep

# can find 
c= 'siong+auto+enterprise'
# cannot find 
d= 'dk+motor+sdn+bhd'

st=[c,d]

for i in st:
    url = f'https://www.google.com.my/search?q={i}&start=0'
    header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    divs = soup.find('div', class_='Z1hOCe')
    try:
        address = divs.find('span', class_='LrzXr').text
    except:
        address = ''
    try:
        company = soup.find_all('h2', class_='qrShPb kno-ecr-pt PZPZlf mfMhoc')[0].text
    except:
        company = ''

    print(i, company, address)
    sleep(2)
    # print('slept 5s')
```

Comment: can you share the exact endpoint of both compnies url

Comment: They should look like these:

https://www.google.com.my/search?q=siong+auto+enterprise&start=0
https://www.google.com.my/search?q=dk+motor+sdn+bhd&start=0

I'm assigning them as a variable so I can fetch the html through requests.

Comment: From your updated code `siong+auto+enterprise`  does not have address so in except you put if next site is containing that address and find span or any tag contain that address